# ASP.NET MVC4 with Razor - Filtering dropdownlist by value selected from another dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have to filter the options of a dropdownlist by value selected from another dropdown. In my database I have a table with all countries and a table with all cities of the world with a FK to the respective country.

Here is a part of my view and my page:

[image: View]

And my controller methods (the GET method of the page, the loading of all countries and the loading of all cities of a country): (I removed the image)

I have to handle the "onchange" event of the first dropdownlist to modify all the options of the second (calling the LoadCities method in my controller and passing the value of the selected item of first drop) but I have no idea about how to do it.

Thank you for your help!!

#### UDPADE

Thank @Shyju for your advices but it still does not working. I am a student and I don't know much about the topic, here are the results:
[image: Network Tab]
You can see that the Content-Length is 0, in fact the response panel is empty.
Why the type is xml? What is "X-Requested-With"? How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not post code (or other text for that matter) as images, it should be copy/pasted and formatted as code in your question.

Comment: Search for MVC cascading dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Use the onchange method (client side) of the first select and fill up seconds' options with an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the change event on the first dropdown(Country), read the value of the selected option and make an ajax call to your server to get the cities for that country.

```
$(function(){

  $("#Country").change(function(){

     var countryId = $(this).val();
     var url = "@Url.Action("LoadCities,"Country")"+countryId;

     $.getJSON(url,function(data){

         var options="";
         $.each(data,function(a,b){
           options+="<option value='"+ b.Value +"'>" + b.Text + "</option>";
         });        
         $("#City").html(options);
     });

  });

});
```

Now your `LoadCities` should return the list of citites as Json.

```
public ActionResult GetCities(int id)
{
   // I am hard coding a bunch of cities for demo. 
   // You may replace with your code which reads from your db table.
   var dummyCities = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
     new SelectListItem { Value="1", Text="Detroit"},
     new SelectListItem { Value="2", Text="Ann Arbor"},
     new SelectListItem { Value="3", Text="Austin"}
   };
   return Json(dummyCities,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I have modified the jQuery code like this:
   ...
   var url = "@Url.Action("GetCities", "Account")";
   $.getJSON(url, { "id" : countryId }, function (data) ......
   ...

I also tried your version (I fixed some syntax errors):
   ...
   var url = "@Url.Action("LoadCities","Account")/"+countryId;
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) .......
   ...

Using FireBug, I saw that the request finds the source (it returns 200 OK) but in the respose the Content-Length is 0 and anythings change in the page (it does not work).

Comment: I also saw, using FireBug and breakpoints in jQuery code, that the executor hit the breakpoints at getJSON(...) line but he jump immediately out without getting into the function.
Least, I noticed that breakpoints in my ActionResult method in my controller have not been hit.
Thanks for your useful advices!

Comment: check your browser net work tab to see whether your code is making the ajax call. put a `console.log(data)` inside the getJSON callback method and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript or jquery OnChange method.
and pass the 1st dropdown Id and use ajax to call the method by passing dropdown Id.

```
<div class="ui-widget">
        <select id="pick">
            <option value="">Select one...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>

        <select id="drop">
            <option value="">Select one...</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
        </select>
    </div>

$("#drop").change(function () {
        var end = this.value;
        var firstDropVal = $('#pick').val();
    });
```

Comment: Any example to demonstrate your suggestion?