# Show list after select DropDownList value Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, single-page-application

I've been working for a while on this, I know how to resolve it using JQuery, but I need to solve this just using server side code, I'm in a `Razor View` 
The thing is:

I have an `@Html.DropDownlist` that is showing some States from USA, and once clicked one of the States from the `DropDownList` then I want to show some cities that belong to the State selected using other DropDownList, I'm not sure how to get the value from the selected field just using `Razor syntax` and then show the cities that belong to the State in other DropDownList when one State is selected, I'm using a `SelectList` and I have an `StateID` to bind the cities... I'm showing all the States inside a `DropDownList` that is working.
Here is my code:

These are just two classes that I'm using to fill the SelectList with some properties:

```
 public States(int id, string name, List<string> list)
        {
            StateID = id;
            Name = name;
            Cities = list;
        }
        public int StateID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Cities { get; set; }
    }


    public static class Fill
    {
        public static List<States> GiveMeStates()
        {
            List<States> li = new List<States>() {
             new States(1, "Alabama",new List<string> {"Adamsville", "Addison", "Anderson","Anniston", "Arab" }),
             new States(2,"Alaska", new List<string> {"Anchorage","Juneau","Fairbanks","Sitka"}),
             new States(3,"Arizona", new List<string> { "Avondale", "Benson", "Besbee"})
            };
            return li;
        }
    }
```

And now this is my Razor View:

```
@using RazorMVC.Models;

@{ 
    List<States> aux = Fill.GiveMeStates();   
    SelectList states = new SelectList(aux, "StateID", "Name");
}
<form>
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlStates", states);

</form>
```

Comment: You need to post your form to a method that redirects to another method that displays the cities based on the selected state (and pass the value of the selected state to that method)

Comment: Why you don't want to use `JQuery` ? I think for binding multi level `dropdown` JQuery is good option, without any postback to page !

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the idea, I understand what you say, but how  would I post my form on selecting an element from the dropdownlist and without a submit button? Is that possible without using a submit button? I'm not sure how to do that just using C# and Razor syntax, thanks again :)

Comment: @SunilKumar I think the same, the guy that ask me for this was very explicit about not to use .js  so I need to figure it out this way ;)

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript, then you must use a submit button. But why would you not want a submit button?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, I know now that's the way hehe, I'll try to solve it that way and I'll let you know, I just was wondering if it was possible to solve it using just Razor syntax on selecting an element without a submit button but yo gave me the answer now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely do not want to use javascript/jQuery, you may submit the form (with the selected state id) and get the states based on the posted state id and show that.

Assuming you want to show the cities for the selected state in the same view.

```
@{

  var stateId = Request.QueryString["ddlStates"] as string;
  List<States> aux = Fill.GiveMeStates();
  SelectList states = new SelectList(aux, "StateID", "Name");
  List<SelectListItem> cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stateId))
  {       
    var state = aux.FirstOrDefault(f => f.StateID == Convert.ToInt32(stateId));
    if (state != null)
    {
        cities = state.Cities
                      .Select(x => new SelectListItem {Value = x, Text = x}).ToList();
    }
  }
}
<label>Select a state and hit submit </label>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
  @Html.DropDownList("ddlStates", states)
  <label>Cities < /label>
  @Html.DropDownList("City", cities)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

I personally prefer to not put a lot of C# code in the razor views. I usually create a view model and use that to pass the values needed in the view. So most of the above code you see in the view goes in my action method.

If you prefer to use jQuery/javascript (Why not ?), You may listen to the change event of the the first dropdown ,get the selected option value and send that to server via an ajax call. Let your server action method returns the states in json format and your ajax metod's call back can parse the json data and update the cities dropdown. Here is a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36815698/40521) to start with